# Native GraalVM compilation fail when reading environment variables with System.getenv(" ")

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, temporal-workflow

The below code is giving error when trying to compilate to native image, using Quarkus native image build.

```
val temporalServerAddress: String = System.getenv("TEMPORAL_SERVER") ?: "127.0.0.1:7233"
val service = WorkflowServiceStubs.newServiceStubs(
    WorkflowServiceStubsOptions.newBuilder().setTarget(temporalServerAddress).build()
)
```

Error

> Java version: 20.0.2+9, vendor version: GraalVM CE 20.0.2+9.1  Graal
> compiler: optimization level: 2, target machine: armv8-a  C compiler:
> cc (apple, arm64, 14.0.3)  Garbage collector: Serial GC (max heap
> size: 80% of RAM)  3 user-specific feature(s)
>
> - com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature
> - io.quarkus.runner.Feature: Auto-generated class by Quarkus from the existing extensions
> - io.quarkus.runtime.graal.DisableLoggingFeature: Disables INFO logging during the analysis phase Warning:
>   RecomputeFieldValue.FieldOffset automatic substitution failed. The
>   automatic substitution registration was attempted because a call to
>   sun.misc.Unsafe.objectFieldOffset(Field) was detected in the static
>   initializer of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil. Detailed failure
>   reason(s): The argument of
>   sun.misc.Unsafe.objectFieldOffset(java.lang.reflect.Field) is not a
>   constant value or a field load that can be constant-folded., Could not
>   determine the field where the value produced by the call to
>   sun.misc.Unsafe.objectFieldOffset(Field) for the field offset
>   computation is stored. The call is not directly followed by a field
>   store or by a sign extend node followed directly by a field store.
>   [2/8] Performing analysis...  []
>   (9.0s @ 1.16GB)    7,709 (78.54%) of  9,816 types reachable   10,011
>   (47.18%) of 21,217 fields reachable   35,513 (37.18%) of 95,505
>   methods reachable    2,616 types,   101 fields, and 1,788 methods
>   registered for reflection
>   1 native library: -framework CoreServices
>
> Fatal error:
> com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError$ParsingError: Error
> encountered while parsing
> io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkNpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator.(JdkNpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator.java:27)
> Parsing context:    at static root method.(Unknown Source)
>
> ```
>     at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError.parsingError(AnalysisError.java:149)
> ```